# Flutter - Play custom sounds updated?

Tags: audio, dart, flutter

I am trying to play a custom mp3 sounds in flutter. I found this proof-of-concept plugin:

https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter-mediaplayer-plugin

But it says that it is outdated. Also, it doesn't find the PlatformMessages class (which I guess should be in services.dart)

Any fix or other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

This repo is more recent,

https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter_audio

and have an example

https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter_audio/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: It says that it won't work with the latest Flutter api update, which version is it refering to?

Comment: The last change was 2 weeks ago, so I guess the logic is here, probably a problem of class/method naming

Comment: still not working :/ Giving me some errors as soon as I put it into my directory

Comment: I am not the maintainer of this plugin, so you should directly contact him, post an issue or fork and do the change yourself, like I said, it should not be complicated