# Play a Custom Sound in Flutter

Tags: android, audio, flutter

I'm trying to Play a custom mp3 sound I've put in an asset folder into the app folder, like you would do for a font or an image file, but then I don't really know how to proceed. I think I might need to register the audio file into the pubspec.yaml, but how?

And how do I play it?

I've checked out this two answer: 
[How to play a custom sound in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813386/how-to-play-a-custom-sound-in-flutter)

[Flutter - Play custom sounds updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083512/flutter-play-custom-sounds-updated)

But the first one is too old and the second one uses URLs as the sound path: `const kUrl2 = "http://www.rxlabz.com/labz/audio.mp3";` and the sound I like to play is in the app, not online. So... How can I do it?

This Is My Current Code, as You can see, there's only a Floating Button.
And I need To Start The Sound at the Point I stated it in the code.

But visual studio underlines in red Various Parts: 
**await**: it says that await is unrecognized.
**audioPlugin.play**: is says It's also unrecognized

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
File tempFile = new File('${tempDir.path}/demo.mp3');
await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
AudioPlayer audioPlugin = new AudioPlayer();


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      print("Button Pressed");

      ///
      /// 
      /// 
      /// Here I Need To start Playing the Sound
      /// 
      /// 
      /// 
      /// 
      audioPlugin.play(tempFile.uri.toString(), isLocal: true);

    });
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers use this package and check out the example given on the package url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not pretty, but...

Add the mp3 file to the assets folder and add it to `pubspec.yaml` like [this](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#introduction).

Load the asset as binary data with `rootBundle.load(asset)`

Use `path_provider` to get the app's temp folder location

Use regular `dart:io` to open a file in `tempDir` (maybe use the asset name) and write `bytes` to it.

Form a `file` URL from the temporary file name in the form `file:///folderPath/fileName`

Pass this to [audioplayer](https://github.com/rxlabz/audioplayer), setting `isLocal` to true (needed on iOS).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:audioplayer/audioplayer.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Audio Player Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlugin = AudioPlayer();
  String mp3Uri;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _load();
  }

  Future<Null> _load() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/demo.mp3');
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/demo.mp3');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
    mp3Uri = tempFile.uri.toString();
    print('finished loading, uri=$mp3Uri');
  }

  void _playSound() {
    if (mp3Uri != null) {
      audioPlugin.play(mp3Uri, isLocal: true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Audio Player Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _playSound,
        tooltip: 'Play',
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've two problems, It says that rootBundle is unknown, but does not tell me to import anything, and I am wuite new to flutter and dart, so could you write as lines of code the last three things you told me to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure you have `import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;`

Comment: I imported the services.dart but it still gives me an error on *await*.

Comment: you had statements that weren't parts of code blocks

Answer (score 2):

Use the audioplayers package =>  https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

*Add the key to plist for iOS Support*

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Add dependencies to pubspec.yaml file

```
audioplayers: ^0.13.2
```

Flutter code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class AudioTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AudioTestState createState() => _AudioTestState();
}

class _AudioTestState extends State<AudioTest> {

  static AudioCache _player = AudioCache();
  static const _audioPath = "count_down.mp3";
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  Future<AudioPlayer> playAudio() async {
    return _player.play(_audioPath);
  }

  void _stop(){
    if (_audioPlayer != null) {
      _audioPlayer.stop();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    playAudio().then((player) {
      _audioPlayer = player;
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return homeScreen();
  }

  Widget homeScreen() {
    return Scaffold();
    //Enter your code here
  }
}
```