# How to use SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click) in android?

Tags: android, flutter

I made an app which should produce a click sound when a button is clicked.

I've tried the code bellow and it didn't work.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
...
SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.click);
```

I expect the app produce sound when a button is clicked, but it didn't. I work on an Android app.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917158/1679754)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Add a sound in `res/raw` folder of your project and then
 RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
    getApplicationContext(),
    Uri.parse("android.resource://" + YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.raw.soundFileInRawfolder)
    ).play();</del>

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43813934/6017001) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52842613/6017001) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902132/6017001)